# Chrome Extension - Detecting New Posts on a 4chan thread

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm wiring a Chrome extension which needs to be able to detect whenever a thread on 4chan has been updated (threads autoupdate). I've tried using a MutationObserver, but it is being set off too many times (4chan thread pages change often for a variety of reasons outside of new posts, including hovering over/expanding images, viewing post replies, opening the reply dialog, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm at work, so I can't visit 4chan to help you more specifically :^)

But, you should find out the distinguishing class or attribute of each post, *e.g.* by using Chrome's Inspect, store the last post ID (*i.e.* the dubs, trips, quads-meter), and on each mutation event, check if the last post ID matches the previous post ID, to determine whether there has been new posts.

There is probably a more efficient way to detect only posts, but this should do the job just fine, if you're already familiar with MutationObserver.